# finding some text and removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to find the way to handle the following code:

```
var rem = $('#Container2').find("table:first").find('tr>td>font:contains("My Placement Text")');
                    alert(rem);
```

i am getting object object, i want to remove the font tag if the `contains` find the `text`. how can i make a change to do it in `jquery`. How can i handle this, like should i use the `text()` tag for the rem variable, i am not sure about it...

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Also, the [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tag is long both deprecated, and obsoleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the `object object` which is a jquery object by calling  the `remove` method on that object

```
$('#Container2')
    .find("table:first")
    .find('tr>td>font:contains("My Placement Text")')
    .remove();
```